# HTMLUnit EcmaError TypeError

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to get data from the URL "https://www.mtgstocks.com/lists/1". Through HTMLUnit I'm getting this error and I'm not sure where to go from here. I don't even understand what the error means.

First this is my code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    try {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.mtgstocks.com/lists/1");
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[1] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js] message=[TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object (https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js#1)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object (https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js#1)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:898)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:778)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:754)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:980)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:781)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:738)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1243)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1143)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:226)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:345)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3154)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2117)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:945)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:521)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:472)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:988)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:246)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:520)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:459)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:444)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object (https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js#1)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError1(ScriptRuntime.java:3934)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.ensureScriptableObject(ScriptableObject.java:2194)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.NativeObject.execIdCall(NativeObject.java:335)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:94)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1540)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:416)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:292)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:769)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:883)
... 32 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object (https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js#1)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError1(ScriptRuntime.java:3934)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.ensureScriptableObject(ScriptableObject.java:2194)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.NativeObject.execIdCall(NativeObject.java:335)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:94)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1540)
at script(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js:1)
at script(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js:50)
at script(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js:1)
at script(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js:1)
at script(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js:1)
at script.r(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/inline.c4ea8b629bf43d39fe04.bundle.js:1)
at script(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js:1)
at script.r(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/inline.c4ea8b629bf43d39fe04.bundle.js:1)
at script(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js:1)
at script.r(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/inline.c4ea8b629bf43d39fe04.bundle.js:1)
at script(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js:1)
at script.r(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/inline.c4ea8b629bf43d39fe04.bundle.js:1)
at script(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/inline.c4ea8b629bf43d39fe04.bundle.js:1)
at script(https://www.mtgstocks.com:443/polyfills.eec762705290a3a04ae2.bundle.js:1)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:416)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:292)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:769)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:883)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:778)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:754)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:980)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:781)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:738)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1243)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1143)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:226)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:345)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3154)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2117)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:945)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:521)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:472)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:988)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:246)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:520)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:459)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:444)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:17)
======= EXCEPTION END ========

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an bug in HtmlUnit. Please open an issue.